# solr custom authentication plugin steps

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud, custom-authentication

I created a custom authorization plugin(a FAT jar) and placed the same in classpath (/usr/local/bin/solr-6.2.1/server/solr-webapp/webapp/libs
) I ran the command to add

created a security.json

```
**{
"authentication":{
   "class":"com.xyz.abc.auth.solrAuthPlugin"
}}**
```

solrAuthPlugin extends AuthorizationPlugin

Then I added the value to zookeeper using the below command

```
server/scripts/cloud-scripts/zkcli.sh -zkhost localhost:9983 -cmd putfile /security.json security.json
```

But after this when I try accessing this in
url http://localhost:8983/solr/indexname/config/overlay I dont get my custom security jar
also

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/authentication
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "errorMessages":["No authentication configured"]}
```

Can someone please tell me how to run and test custom authorization plugin in solr , or am I missing some step

Comment: Please note ** is not a part of security.json